# Extend home router Wi-Fi range using a laptop with two Wi-Fi devices

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I'm running Windows 10 on a laptop which has two Wi-Fi devices, the one that comes with the laptop and a USB Wisacom WS-HP1000 (RTL8187L) which I already had. As my router Wi-Fi range is poor I'm trying to use the laptop to extend the Wi-Fi range all over the house using the laptop as an Access Point but I'm unable to successfully do it.

What I would like is to use the laptop's integrated Wi-Fi interface to connect to the Wi-Fi router and use the USB RTL8187L device to extend the Wi-Fi range. How should I proceed?

Comment: You are confusing wireless antennas with radios. There are no explicit instructions for Windows 10 yet because existing instructions from Windows Vista/7/8 still work the same: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=windows+10+wireless+repeater

Comment: What do you mean by "You are confusing wireless antennas with radios"? My computer has 2 Wi-Fi antennas, one is connected to the internet and i want to let Wi-Fi clients connect to the second antenna and route traffic to the first one, the one connected to Internet. Could you please elaborate on the supposed confusion? About the specific instructions, your link - which is not specific to the proposed setup, instead it focuses on virtual interfaces which i'm not interested in - does not provide those instructions neither any kind of solution. Last, just note Windows 7/8 instructions would work.

Comment: No, your computer has two WiFi *radios* not two WiFi *antennas*. An antenna does not connect to anything. It does not route anything. The link I provided leads to information relevant to any setup, virtual or otherwise.

Comment: When i said antennas i meant to say devices. Excuses. Also the link you provided leads nowhere, it's just a bunch of links pointing to any setup except the one i asked for.

Comment: Well, if you refuse to read the obvious answer...

Comment: Is that attitude allowed here? Obviously it is... Well, at least at this point i hope you already realized you have no intention on helping and no idea on how to solve the proposed question. You clearly went off topic in you very first answer.

Comment: Where are the moderators when they're needed? Why do i get down voted? What a show...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the integrated *netsh* tool from windows, you also only need one adapter.
Start by pressing the windows key (or open up the startmenu by pressing the button) and start typing *cmd*. When the application shows op on the screen, right click and select *Run as administrator*.

[image: Running cmd as administrator]
*Running cmd as administrator*

You should now see a command prompt, where you will have to enter two commands now. Start with

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork ssid=YOURSSID key=YOURKEY keyusage=persistent
```

where you have to replace

- YOURSSID with a name for your repeated network *
- YOURKEY with a password used to connect to your network

after that (press the *enter* key on your keyboard to finish the command) you type in

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

to activate the new wlan network (press *enter* again, you can close this window now)

[image: Setting up the hostednetwork]
*Setting up the hostednetwork*

Half way done, you have to enable the internet sharing now, so the new network can reach the internet over your current wlan connection.
Start with firing up the *Network & Sharing Center* by right clicking on the Network symbol (*2*) in the Taskbar (you may need to extend (*1*) it first) and than proceed by clicking on *Open Network & Sharing Center* (*3*).

[image: Opening Network & Sharing Center]
*Opening Network & Sharing Center*

You now have to change to the Network adapter section. Do this by clicking on *Change adapter settings* (*1*). Also notice how you can see the new created network already, although it says __No network connection_ (*2*).

[image: Changing to the adapter settings]
*Changing to the adapter settings*

In the adapter view you have now to identify the right adapters. First try to find the adapter you try to extend, you can find it easily by looking for your Network name - in my case *NRouter* (*1*). Now do the same for your new network, but look for your new network name now - again in my case *NRouterRepeater* (*2*). Note the adapter name, you will need it in the next step. For me the adapter name for me is *LAN-Verbindung* 5*, this will most likely be different for you.
After identifying both adapters right click on your adapter of the network you want to extend - in my case *WiFi* - and proceed by clicking on *Properties* (*3*).

[image: Identifying the right network adapters]
*Identifying the right network adapters*

In the Property panel you have to change to the *Sharing* Tab (*1*). In there activate the first checkbox (*2*) and select the adapter you want to extend your Network to from the combobox below - in my case *LAN-Verbindung* 5* (*3*). Finish my clicking on *OK* (*4*).

[image: Setting up the internet sharing]
*Setting up the internet sharing*

Give your computer a couple seconds to set things up, when you change back to the *Network & Sharing Center* you should now see your extended network with the status *Internet*.

[image: The extended network in the Network & Sharing Center]
*The extended network in the Network & Sharing Center*

You're done now. If you gave the new network a different SSID (aka name) than your weak network you should be able to connect to the new network as you're used to do. If you set the same SSID and key on the new network your devices should connect automatically.

I hope I could help you!

**You can use the same SSID on both networks, but you should consider that the networks could concur when it comes to signal strength, resulting in devices switching between the two networks over and over again which gives you bad usability. I would recommend using a different name, except you are sure that your devices will not be be able to reach your weak network.*

Comment: That's already in the link I gave him but he says he's not interested.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Somebody did something good for me today, so I'm good with him and give something back, in form of a complete instruction. Why brother with things that make you angry, right?

Comment: Whatever makes you happy :)

Comment: Hi  Kimmax, thanks a lot for the detailed step by step instructions. I already knew i could implement your proposed Hotspot technique on a single Wi-Fi device, as this single device setup was all i could find on Google. But as i has 2 Wi-Fi devices and the USB one has some extra power compared to the laptop integrated one, i wanted to use both devices to extend the Wi-Fi range but i'm unable to find a tutorial with such setup. Meanwhile i'm stuck to the single Wi-Fi device setup. Hope someone can give a hint and thanks a lot for the time invested on your detailed reply :D

Comment: @user846226 It's kind of hacky, but you can disable the primary adapter while executing `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`, this will start the hostednetwork on your secondary (usb) adapter. You can disable the adapter in the Adapter view (Picture 5) by right clicking the primary adapter (the one you set the internet sharing on) and selecting _Deactiviate_. Don't forget to re-enable tho :D Let me know if you need help somewhere